# copyFile from fs function is undefined in Electron js by using Quasar js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, quasar-framework

I have read [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) which introduces on working fs (file-system) in Node js, but I can not manage it to work in my Quasar js application in Electron app. There are the some codes:

```
<script>
import fs from 'fs';
export default {
  // some another codes here
  methods: {
    save() {
        console.log(fs.copyFile) // gives undefined
        fs.copyFile("source.jpg", ("destination.jpg" , (err) => {
          console.log(err)
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The code gives that error:

```
Map.vue?108f:119 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.copyFile is not a function
    at eval (Map.vue?108f:119)
```

Additional quasar (vue) js files:
*package.json*

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "sequelize-file": "^0.3.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^2.0.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^9.4.4",
    "electron-debug": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.1",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^2.3.5"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error attempts I have found the solution for the problem, it was enough easy to use `fs` in Electron app with Quasar js. In Quasar js, there are some its own configurations which are ready to use. In my case, just must import `fs` looks like following:

```
var remote = window.electron.remote;
var fs = remote.require("fs");
```